# ¿Cómo completar con ceros el valor de una variable en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo una variable:

```
$numero = 1;
```

Me gustaría que al imprimirla con `echo $numero;` imprimiera `01`, es decir, 2 dígitos.

¿Es posible?

Comment: **En contra del voto de cierre**: esta pregunta atrajo mejores y más completas respuestas, por lo que lo lógico sería poner a la otra como duplicada de esta. Hagamos canónico lo bueno, no lo primero.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Utiliza [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php):

```
$n = 5;
printf('%02d', $n);
```

Mostrará "05". Si el número tiene más de un dígito lo mostrará con normalidad.

Comment: Hola, esto me funciona si quiero imprimir, y si ahora quiero guardar en una variable el 05? Sin que se guarde el 5 sólo?

Comment: @KikuS. utiliza `sprintf()` con el mismo formato.

Answer (score 16):

Otra forma más de hacerlo:

```
<?php
$numero = 1;
$numeroConCeros = str_pad($numero, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo $numeroConCeros;
```

La ventaja de usar [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php), es que puedes modificar el número de espacios a rellenar con solo cambiar el 2º parámetro, o el carácter de relleno cambiando el 3º parámetro. Además puedes pasar un 4º parámetro con los valores `STR_PAD_LEFT`, `STR_PAD_RIGHT` o `STR_PAD_BOTH` para rellenar por la izquierda, derecha o ambos lados de la cadena original.

Answer (score 9):

Quiero aportar esta pequeña función *hand made*:

<kbd>[**DEMO REXTESTER**](http://rextester.com/WSDB78391)</kbd>

```
<?php 

/*
 * zero_fill
 *
 * Rellena con ceros a la izquierda
 *
 * @param $valor valor a rellenar
 * @param $long longitud total del valor
 * @return valor rellenado
 */

function zero_fill ($valor, $long = 0)
{
    return str_pad($valor, $long, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

?>
```

---

```
//Ejemplos de uso

<?php 

echo zero_fill(5, 4)."\n";
echo zero_fill(47,0)."\n";
echo zero_fill(1000)."\n";
echo zero_fill(1000,50)."\n";
echo zero_fill(23,-1000)."\n";

 ?>
```

**Resultado:**

```
0005
47
1000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000
23
```

Comment: [hand made ??](http://lucdebrouwer.nl/how-to-zero-fill-a-number-in-php/)

Comment: Correcto @aldanux, _hand made_, aunque más de uno ha escrito algo parecido, por ejemplo [aquí](https://joshtronic.com/2014/03/24/how-to-zero-fill-a-number/)   y [aquí](https://coderwall.com/p/tavyqa/php-zero-fill) tienes el mismo código, sin ser una función. Es más, tu duda permitirá que la función sea mejorada, pues se puede mejorar. Y, _hand made_ indica que no existe en el core de PHP, cuando no la he trabajado yo suelo colocar el enlace de la fuente. [Aquí la función `sub_date`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99364/29967)  también es _hand made_. Uno es libre de crear sus funciones.