# Añadir 0 a la izquierda

Tags: php, sql

Como puedo indicar en esta sentencia SQL que me añada un 0 a la izquierda?

```
$suma = $res['MAX(num_documento)']+01;
```

Comment: es algo bastante *basico*. Qué has probado? ante dudas asi trata de investigar y hacerlo tu mismo.. en vez de preguntar directamente

Comment: Puedes obtener los datos tal cual de la base de datos, y una vez obtenidos, hacerlo desde PHP, [de esta manera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74997/29967). Es mucho más eficaz que formatear los datos al momento de hacer la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Solución a mi problema me costo entender un poco el str_pad pero lo logre

```
str_pad($suma,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Con esto ya imprime ese deseado cero a la izquierda, si se quiere más cero el segundo parametro es el que da el total de numeros que dispondra