# Insertar una fecha anterior a la prevista

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Tengo una tabla llamada entregas, dentro de ella 2 campos `fecha_preparar` y `fecha_entrega`.

```
$fecha_prepararse = fecha_entrega - 4 dias

INSERT INTO entregas (fecha_entrega, fecha_preparar)
VALUES ('$fecha_entrega', '$fecha_prepararse');
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que al insertar `fecha_entrega` automáticamente me inserte `fecha_preparar` con 4 días menos de `fecha_entrega` (el formato debe ser en ambas fechas datetime).

El resultado debería ser algo así ejemplo:

> fecha_entrega = 2017-09-05 00:00:00
>
> fecha_preparar = 2017-09-01 00:00:00

Ahora tengo este caso:

```html
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_ENTREGAS . " set fecha_preparacion = '" . date_sub($fecha_entrega,INTERVAL 4 DAY) . "' where entregas_id = '" . (int)$entregas_id . "'");
```

No se ejecuta el update, me da el siguiente error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '4' (T_LNUMBER)

Comment: ¿La respuesta dada no resolvió el problema finalmente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Opción 1: con MySQL

Puedes usar [`date_sub`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), escribiendo la consulta así:

```
$fecha_entrega="2017-09-05 00:00:00";



INSERT INTO entregas (fecha_entrega, fecha_preparar))
    VALUES 
    ($fecha_entrega, date_sub($fecha_entrega,INTERVAL 4 DAY));
```

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/YUYQ83689)

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS restar_fecha (
                id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                preparar DATETIME NOT NULL,
                entregar DATETIME NOT NULL
    );



INSERT INTO restar_fecha (entregar, preparar)
    VALUES 
    ('2017-09-05 00:00:00',date_sub('2017-09-05 00:00:00',INTERVAL 4 DAY)),
    ('2017-09-15 21:00:00',date_sub('2017-09-15 21:00:00',INTERVAL 4 DAY))

;


SELECT * FROM restar_fecha;
```

#### `Resultado`:

```
id  preparar                  entregar
1   01.09.2017 00:00:00       05.09.2017 00:00:00
2   11.09.2017 21:00:00       15.09.2017 21:00:00
```

---

### Opción 2: con PHP

Puedes usar [`DateTime::sub`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/SCN45306)

```
<?php 

$fecha_e = new DateTime('2017-09-05 00:00:00');
$fecha_entrega=$fecha_e->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "\n";

$fecha_p=$fecha_e->sub(new DateInterval('P4D'));
$fecha_prepara=$fecha_p->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;

echo "Fecha entrega: ".$fecha_entrega. "\n";
echo "Fecha prepara: ".$fecha_prepara. "\n";

/* SQL Se recomienda mejor usar consultas preparadas*/

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (entrega, prepara) 
            VALUES ($fecha_entrega, $fecha_prepara);";

?>
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
Fecha entrega: 2017-09-05 00:00:00

Fecha prepara: 2017-09-01 00:00:00
```

---

Podemos también una función PHP que de más flexibilidad al uso del código, en caso de que necesitemos ejecutar la operación en múltiples partes de una aplicación:

```
/**
 * Sustraer intervalo a una fecha dada.
 *
 *
 * @param  datetime $fecha_inicial : fecha dada.
 * @param  string   $intervalo     : Intervalo de días a sustraer.
 * @param  string   $formato       : Formato de salida de la fecha/hora.
 * @return array    $fechas        : Fechas resultantes.
 */

function sub_date ($fecha_inicial, $intervalo, $formato)
{
    $fecha_i = new DateTime($fecha_inicial);
    $fecha_inicial=$fecha_i->format($formato);

    $fecha_s=$fecha_i->sub(new DateInterval($intervalo));
    $fecha_sub=$fecha_s->format($formato) ;
    $fechas=array("inicial"=>$fecha_inicial, "sub"=>$fecha_sub);
    return $fechas;
}
```

La función crearía un array parecido a este:

```
Array
(
    [inicial] => 2017-09-05 00:00:00
    [sub] => 2017-09-01 00:00:00
)
```

Aquí un código de prueba de la función. Podemos pasar en parámetro no sólo la fecha, sino también el intervalo que queremos sustraer, y en qué formato queremos los resultados:

```
/*Probando la función*/

$arrFechas=sub_date('2017-09-05 00:00:00','P4D','Y-m-d H:i:s');
print_r($arrFechas);
echo "Entrega: ".$arrFechas["inicial"]."\n";
echo "Prepara: ".$arrFechas["sub"]."\n";

--- Resultado

Entrega: 2017-09-05 00:00:00
Prepara: 2017-09-01 00:00:00
```

> **Nota:** Para dar más seguridad al código, conviene el uso de consultas preparadas.

Comment: Gracias justo lo que necesito

Comment: muy buena respuesta, ahora tengo un detalle no realiza un update he agregado al final de la pregunta el codigo.

Comment: No se ejecuta el update, me da el siguiente error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '4' (T_LNUMBER)

Comment: ya abri la pregunta

Comment: @IvanDiazPerez al parecer la otra pregunta ya tiene solución. Stackoverflow funciona _por preguntas_. Si planteas una pregunta con un problema concreto y la respuesta dada soluciona _ese_ problema debes darla como solucionada. Si luego surge un problema posterior debes abrir _otra_ pregunta con el nuevo problema. Por esto te pregunté si esta respuesta no ha resuelto tu problema. No es buena idea, después que un problema está solucionado, editar la pregunta para plantear una situación diferente a la situación inicial. En cierto sentido es minusvalorar el esfuerzo que hacemos por responder.