# ¿Como aumentar 30 dias a una fecha al guardar datos en una tabla?

Tags: php

Saludos, mi problema es que cuando hago la inserción de las fechas a pagar por cada persona debo primero insertar la fecha de inicio del alquiler, luego a esa misma fecha aumentarle un mes y asi con las demas fechas. Por ejemplo el usuario alquila el el local 4 meses, la primera fecha de pago va a ser el 05-09-2017 luego la proxima fecha sera el 05-10-2017 y asi ira aumentando según los meses que haga el alquiler. He intentado con esto pero no me hace los aumentos:

```
$estado=0;
$aumento = 0.2;
$aumentaCada = 3;
$concepto = 0;

for($i = $aumentaCada; $i < $repetir; $i+$aumentaCada){
  if(($i>0) && ($i % $aumentaCada)==0):
    $monto = $monto*(1+$aumento);
  endif;

  $primer = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$primer + 30 day"));
  $concepto = $concepto +1;

  $query3 = "INSERT INTO 
  pagos_usuarios(id_inscripcion,concepto,monto,estado,fecha_a_pagar)
  VALUES('$val2','$concepto','$monto','$estado','$primer')";
  $sql3=$mysqli->query($query3);
  }
```

Asi ha quedado, pero de esa forma no me inserta nada, y se queda como en un bug infinito.

Comment: hola!! y como esta quedando?

Comment: Hola gbianchi, pues me esta aumentando demasiado, me aumenta 2 meses. y el aumento lo hace a todas las fechas.

Comment: falta toda una parte del codigo no? esta es la parte que aumenta.. y como se graba y donde grabas?

Comment: Ya te coloco todo gbianchi

Comment: gbianchi ese $aumentaCada = 3, es porque cada 3 meses sube el monto del alquiler. Pero es curioso que el aumento de la fecha lo he metido dentro de ese for y es la forma en la que he estado mas cerca de que haga bien los aumentos de fecha.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Insertar una fecha anterior a la prevista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99360/insertar-una-fecha-anterior-a-la-prevista) Hace poco **[respondí a una pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99364/29967)**, usando código MySQL o bien mediante una función PHP.

Comment: Que valor tiene $repetir?

Comment: tiene un numero, es la cantidad de veces que le digo que va a repetir la acción. Por como mencione un usuario puede alquilar varios meses un local, entonces por ejemplo lo quiere 4 meses, le paso ese 4 en $repetir para que me inserte los 4 montos de cada mes y las 4 fechas a pagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considera estos ajustes, `$i` sera cada mes

```
$estado=0;
$aumento = 0.2;
$aumentaCada = 3;
$concepto = 0;

//fecha inicial
$primer=date('d-m-Y');

//for inicia en mes 1, se incrementa de 1 en 1 porque debes registrar por cada mes
for($i = 1; $i < ($repetir+1); $i++){
    //monto incrementa solo en multiplos del 3er mes
    if(($i % $aumentaCada)==0){
        $monto = $monto*(1+$aumento);
    }
    //el primer insert debe tener la primera fecha, entonces se suma a partir del 2do mes
    if($i>1){
        $primer = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$primer + 30 day"));
    }

    $concepto = $concepto +1;

    $query3 = "INSERT INTO 
    pagos_usuarios(id_inscripcion,concepto,monto,estado,fecha_a_pagar)
    VALUES('$val2','$concepto','$monto','$estado','$primer')";
    $sql3=$mysqli->query($query3);
}
```

Comment: Hola julio, ha pasado lo mismo, sigue aumentadole un mes a la fecha inicial, no me guarda la fecha inicial. Lo unico que se me ha ocurrido es que cuando consulte las fechas de pago, luego de asociar la consulta hacerle la misma operación con el srtotime pero restandole 1 mes, y pues asi me ha funcionado.

Comment: no has publicado la declaración de fecha inicial, deberia estar asi: $primer=date('d-m-Y'); la incluire en la respuesta

Comment: Exactamente en ese formato esta, lo que pasa es que esa fecha me la traigo de una consulta a la base de datos, es una fecha que ya esta guardada. Porque cada local tiene su fecha de disponibilidad. La cual vendria siendo esa fecha inicial, pero en efecto esta en ese formato

Comment: Entonces en el primer registro, debe grabarse la fecha obtenida de esa consulta? Publica el código donde declaras $primer.

Comment: Explico mejor, esa fecha yo la registro cuando voy a aperturar un local, le pongo todos sus datos, y registro la fecha en que comienza a estar disponible ej: 04-09-2017, luego cuando alguien va a alquilar un local, tengo un formulario en donde escojo el local que desee, esos locales los muestro en un select, según el que escoja me muestra en otro input la fecha en la que esta disponible, luego cuando proceso el alquiler esa fecha la mando en ese input con su respectivo name, y la recibo en la funcion alquiler (y aqui a parte de todos los datos que guardo le paso $primer)

Comment: Entonces la fecha la obtienes algo así: $primer = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($fecharecibida)); donde fecha recibida debe tener formato "2011-01-07" (YYYY-mm-dd); Necesito ver esa fecha, porque no creo que el problema este en el for.

Comment: function alquiler($names,$ced,$direc,$tlfm,$monto,$primer,$repetir) esta es mi función, aqui recibo $primer, y $repetir los cuales mando desde el formulario de registro de alquiler. Dentro de la función lo que hago es la operacion que tengo en la pregunta, hago el aumento de una vez, la fecha la recibo tal cual como la envio.

Comment: Para descartar el problema, pon la primera fecha en duro, asi: $primer = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("2011-01-07")); y verifica si aun asi le suma un mes al primer registro.

Comment: exactamente le sigue sumando el mismo mes a la fecha. La verdad ya no tengo idea que esta pasando, la única solución que pienso es lo que mencione que cuando vaya a consultar esas fechas, luego de la consulta le reste 1 mes a la fecha.

Comment: Hay la posiblidad que tengas un trigger? que este actualizando la fecha sin que te des cuenta.

Comment: No, no creo que exista esa posibilidad.! Cual seria la mejor forma de comprobar si tengo uno?

Comment: Probé el código y funciona normal, por lo que podría ser un trigger. para descartar realiza un insert directamente a la BD desde algún cliente de mysql y verifica que se registre la fecha exacta que colocas.

Comment: Es curioso, lo he hecho julio. Y ha insertado bien la fecha. Me tiene la cabeza hecha un hueco esto.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65059/discussion-between-juliocpiro-and-alejo-mendoza).

Comment: Después de prueba se determino que era un trigger.

Comment: Exactamente ese era el problema. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cambiando un poco la lógica de tu función se puede solucionar.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $repetir; $i++)
if(($i>0) && ($i % $aumentaCada)==0):
```

Mira los problemas que tiene el for con el if:
Si i es mayor que 0 (entonces por que no poner el caso 0 afuera)
Si es múltiplo de cada cuanto aumenta, entonces porque no aumentar i por cada cuanto aumenta realmente?
el for deberia ser `$i = aumentacada; $i < $repetir; $i+aumentacada`

con eso te ahorras el if adentro del for y también los problemas que estas teniendo posteriormente.

Comment: gbianchi asi lo pense, pero tampoco me ha funcionado, es peor, no me inserta las fechas en la tabla.

Comment: No se si haya otra forma mas facil de ir aumentado 1 mes a la fecha inicial que recibo, y irla guardando.

Comment: como que no te inserta las fechas en las tablas? puedes aclarar como hiciste la función en la pregunta? porque esta es la forma lógica de hacerlo.

Comment: Se ha quedado como en un bug infinito el sistema, y no me guarda nada en la tabla.! Asi la he puesto:   $aumentaMes = 1;

  for($i=$aumentaMes; $i<$repetir; $i+$aumentaMes){
      $primer = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("$primer + 1 month"));
  }

Comment: por favor aclara en la pregunta como quedo tu funcion completa. Usar editar y agregalo como edicion.