# Obtener ultimo registro de MYSQL e incrementarle Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Lo que tengo que conseguir es que me obtenga el último registro y me lo incremente en uno. Se que para obtener el ultimo registro se usa last() pero no se donde tengo que emplearlo. Me sigue agregando el mismo numero sin incrementarlo.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        $documento = new Documento();

        $ultimoDocumento = Documento::orderBy("id", "desc");
        $ultimoAgregado = $documento->$documento_id->last();

        $ultimoAgregado++;


        $documento->documento_id= $ultimoAgregado;
        $documento->save();
    }
```

Los datos los puse a mano, pero tendria que ser algo asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: documento_id es la que tiene que incrementarse

Comment: No, voy a editar la pregunta

Comment: no entiendo la secuencia 4-000001 y luego 5-000002... luego cual seguiría? 6-000003?

Comment: Si, lo que hace es coger la id del propio documento y después la secuencia seguiría en 000001, 000002, 000003 y el problema que me da el codigo que puse es que no me lo incrementa

Comment: Porque en vez de obtener TODOS los elementos de la base de datos y luego buscar el ultimo en el código... porque no consulta mas bien el ultimo ID de la base de datos... el dia que tenga 100.000 registros se le va a romprese script. Algo como `$ultimoDocumento = Documentos::orderBy("id", "desc");` Ahi ya tiene el documento con el ultimo ID y ya sabe como crear el siguiente

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo completar con ceros el valor de una variable en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73996/c%c3%b3mo-completar-con-ceros-el-valor-de-una-variable-en-php)

Comment: Te comento para recuperar el valor que deseas incrementar se hace así: **$valorRecuperado = Documento::latest('id')->value('documento_id');** de ahi en mas revisa la publicación que ya enlace seguro te lo resuelve

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve, esto me funciono a la perfeccion

```
    $valorRecuperado = Documento::latest('id')->value('documento_id');
    $numero_final = str_pad($valorRecuperado, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
    $numero_final++;
    $numero_final = str_pad($numero_final, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```